# jQuery UI Autocomplete box displaying

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a problem with triggering manually jQuery autocomplete box. The source comes with $.ajax and returns json. Also on 'open' function I append some custom items to the box. Now what I need is that when you click on the input then the autocomplete box shall be seen. It does not have to search or anything. Just show the box with custom appended items.

I have tried minLength: 0 and $(this).autocomplete('search', ''); But these aint working. Any help would be appreciated.

Current code:

```
$(".searchBox").autocomplete({
    delay: 300,
    open: function() {
        $('.ui-autocomplete').prepend('<li class="nav-button ui-menu-close"><a href="#">&#215</a></li>');

        var position = $('.ui-autocomplete').position(),
            left = position.left, top = position.right;

        $('.ui-autocomplete').css({left: 0,
            width: "auto",
            'z-index': 1000
        });
        $('.ui-menu-close').on('click', function() {
            $('.searchBox').autocomplete('close');
        });
    },
    source: function(request, response)
    {
        $.ajax({
        url: '/search',
        data: {
            'ajax' : 1,
            'query': request.term
        },
        timeout: 3000,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {                           
            console.log(data)
        },
    });
    },
    minLength: 0
}).focus(function() {
    $(this).data('autocomplete')._trigger('open');
    $(this).trigger('keydown.autocomplete');
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Some code would be nice!

Answer (score 0):

The autocomplete dialog opens only on keydown event:

```
$('#your_autocomplete_field').trigger('keydown');
```

will open autocomplete. Of course there has to be some value inside the field or no search will be performed.

However you say you don't want search mechanism. Then autocomplete is the wrong gadget for you. Maybe you'r looking for **combobox**

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Comment: He mentions that the source comes with `$.ajax`, so it seems like he does want the autocomplete functionality... But also wants the menu to open on `click`... in which case you can bind the `click` event to trigger `keydown`, and if the value of the input is the same as a value that was already looked up, then no additional search will be made, it will just display the same menu... which seems to be his desired functionality

Comment: I tried triggering keydown, but still no menu. Also what tomaroo said is the functionality what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to fight against the other autocomplete events that may hide the list, but this should work:

```
$(".searchBox").click(function() {
    $('.ui-autocomplete').show();
});
```

Comment: This will work but I dont prefer this kind of hack. Native solution would be better if anybody knows one. Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: You can try manually triggering the autocomplete events to see if you get what you need but I don't think any of them will open the menu. Good luck!